# Birational immersion of projective plane

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, projective-varieties

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective $3$-fold. Under what condition on $X$, does there exist a birational immersion from the projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2$ to $X$?

Comment: Can you define exactly what a "birational immersion" is?

Comment: @potentiallydense Birational immersion means immersion on an open subset.

Comment: OK. In that case this question seems very difficult to answer. For example, take any smooth projective 3-fold and blow it up at a point to get $X$. Then $X$ contains a copy of $\mathbf P^2$.

Comment: @user43198: This definition is no different from a map being birational. The latter is equivalent to being an *isomorphism* on an open set.